# Why is the initializion of class members not allowed outside of the constructors?

Tags: c++

In other words, why does the compiler complain about things like this:

```
class Integer {
  int i = 3;
};
```

Although this is a really silly example, there are many cases in which classes have members which can be by default initialized to some value (for example some internal counter which always is default initialized to zero). What is the reason for forbidding these default initializations outside of the class constructors?

Comment: That's fine in C++11. The term to search is "in-class member initialization".

Comment: Because the C++ language committee didn't decide to add that feature?

Comment: @Adam : Well, they _did_ decide to, only 13 years later than we would have liked. :-P

Comment: One of the reasons I hate C++ so much is that it's such a messy aggregation of people asking for stupid features ... and getting them.  One of the things I like about "OO" is the opportunity to set a "contract" for establishing an "invariant condition".  The ability to have a nice, iron clad "constructor".  Sigh...

Comment: @ildjarn, Yet it still isn't implemented in MSVC :/ (at least not in 10 or 11, not sure how 12 is coming along)

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't see how in-class member initializers take that away.

Comment: in-class initialization does not change invariant conditions, it's just a nicer way to set those conditions across many many constructors, without the overhead of having to call out to an init() function from each and every one.

Comment: That is actually the reason why I initially asked the question (yes, I should have stated that on my post... oh well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, in C++11 you actually can do it like you showed. It's still illegal in C++98/C++03 however.

Edit: To answer your question however: I don't know :p maybe the language designers didn't think anyone would want to do that at the time of publishing C++98. In any case you certainly can do it now with C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are constructors.

```
class InTeGeR
{
    Public:
           int i;
           InTeGeR()
            {
                i=3;
            }
 }
```

In presence of out-constructor initialization:

```
class InTeGeR
{
    Public:
           int i=3;
           InTeGeR()
            {
                i=5;
            }
            //now, i could be 3 or 5. Which one? 
            int j=i+1;
            //is j 4 or 6? Very confusing
 }
```

Comment: Well, `InTeGeR() : i(3) {}` would probably make a better example of doing it through constructor.

Comment: The difference is that Andrey's encompasses all of yours, as well as `const` and reference members, and doesn't do any unnecessary extra initialization. There's no downside at all.

Comment: The author already knows that constructors exist. The question was why can't it be done *outside* of constructors.

Comment: Because, outside the constructors, the i variables scope is both before and after the constructors. When you construct, it would be set to 3 again and  the constructor would not have a meaning for i

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: Actually if a class has lots of different types of constructors and one member of the class is some sort of counter which should be initialized to zero, I am forced to initialize it on all of the constructors. It would be nice to be able to avoid this if I wanted (although I would agree with you the code would not be as nice as the one which explicitly initializes everything at the constructors).